# Extracting preprocessor symbols from source

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I'm looking for a way to extract all preprocessor symbols used in my code.
As an example, if my code looks like this:

```
#ifdef FOO
#endif

#if ( BAR == 1 && \
      defined (Z) )
#endif
```

I'd like to get the list `[FOO,BAR,Z]` as the output.

I found some posts suggesting `gcc -E -dM`, but this displays all symbols that the preprocessor would apply to the code.
What I want, in contrast, is a list of all symbols **actually used in the code**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the *complementary thing* you don't want it to do ?

Comment: `gcc -E -dM` displays all symbols that the preprocessor would apply to the code. What I want, in contrast, is a list of all symbols actually used in the code.

Comment: What about preprocessor symbols that are generated using the concatenation operator?

Comment: Not a ready to use answer but [libcpp is open source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libcpp/identifiers.c), if there isn't not a ready-to-use utility you may wrap some code around libcpp to dump all identifiers which are a known macro (note that this will include what paddy highlighted in his comment and it may be not what you want). for sure a starting point. Check also track_macro_expansion option.

Comment: Maybe you could get there via debug info in an elf?  If your code is compiled with the right flags (e.g. `-gdwarf-2 -g3`), [gdb is able to understand macros](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html), including when the macros are #defined / #undefed.  Maybe the dwarf info also contains where the macros are used??

Comment: I am doing something similar.  I wrote a python program to extract all #define symbols and their values.  Then I generate an include-able file that uses "#pragma message..." (in my compiler) to output <SYMBOL>:<VALUE> lines.  not exactly what the OP asked for, but it gets very close to what I need.  I hope the OP keeps us posted on results.

Answer (score 2):

That's quite simple. You have just to parse the source code **exactly** the way a conformant pre-processor would, and with the correct C or C++ version support. Ok, I'm joking, if you support only the later version, your code is likely to produce correct results on older versions - but even this should be thoroughly controlled.

More seriously now. As you can ask the pre-processor to give you the list of all defined symbols, you can simply *tokenize* the source, and identify all tokens from that list that are not immediately following an initial #define or #undef. This part should be reasonably feasable with lex+yacc.

The only alternative I can imagine would be to use the code of a real compiler (Clang should be easier than gcc but unsure) discard all code generation and consistently store every macro usage.

TL/DR: however you take it, it will be a hard work: if you can do without, keep away from that...

Answer (score 0):

You can get half way there by using a preprocessor library such as [Boost.Wave](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/wave/).  It can act as a lexer so you wouldn't have to write that part yourself.  You would have to supply a grammar for the bit you cared about (define, ifdef, ifndef, if, elif) though.