# Regex for capturing preprocessor directive symbols in C# source code

Tags: c#, regex

Given the follow code sample, is there a regular expression that would capture all defined symbols while excluding those that have been commented out?

```
...

#define SYMBOL_1                                          // Match 1, 1 group

#undef   SYMBOL_2                                         // Match 2, 1 group

#pragma warning disable 649

// #undef NO_MATCH

// #undef !NO_MATCH

#if(SYMBOL_3 && SYMBOL_4)                                 // Match 3, 2 groups

#if SYMBOL_3 && SYMBOL_4                                  // Match 4, 2 groups

#elif SYMBOL_3                                            // Match 5, 1 group

#elif   !SYMBOL_3                                         // Match 6, 1 group

   #if (SYMBOL_1 && SYMBOL_2) || !SYMBOL_3 || SYMBOL_4    // Match 7, 4 groups

   #elif SYMBOL_1                                         // Match 8, 1 group

   #elif    !SYMBOL_2                                     // Match 9, 1 group

   #if (SYMBOL_1&&SYMBOL_2) || !SYMBOL_3// || NO_MATCH    // Match 10, 3 groups

   #if (SYMBOL_1&&!SYMBOL_2) || !SYMBOL_3 //|| NO_MATCH   // Match 11, 3 groups

...
```

I've attempted a number of things, but I'm not quite there. The following expression captures the first symbol on each matching line (global and multiline options enabled):

`^[\t ]*#(?>if|elif|define|undef)(?> |\t|\(|\)|!|&|\|)*(\w*)`

Where:

- `^[\t ]*#(?>if|elif|define|undef)` identifies the lines that begin with `#define`, `#undef`, `#if`, and `#elif` that are not commented out. Preceding whitespace and all other preprocessor directives, such as `#pragma` are ignored.
- `(?: |\t|\(|\)|!|&|\|)*` is non-capturing, but allows certain characters (`space`, `tab`, `(`, `)`, `!`, `&`, and `|`) before the symbol.
- and then finally `(\w*)` captures the symbol as a group. All "SYMBOL_#" symbols are captured, while the "NO_MATCH" symbols are not due to preceding comment marks.

[regex101 fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/Ifxepd/2)

Current results:

- Match 1 > Group 1: "SYMBOL_1"
- Match 2 > Group 1: "SYMBOL_2"
- Match 3 > Group 1: "SYMBOL_3", but there's no Group 2 containing "SYMBOL_4".
- ... and so on ...

Matches 3, 4, 7, 10, and 11 should have multiple Groups.

The only thing remaining is to repeat the 2nd (non-capturing) and 3rd (capturing) parts of the expression until the end of the line. That's what I'm stuck on. Currently, 11 matches are made, but only 11 groups are captured. There should be 20 groups.

I have tried simply duplicating those parts a number of times, and that works, but it results in a very long expression and many empty match groups.

For example, `^[\t ]*#(?>if|elif|define|undef)(?> |\t|\(|\)|!|&|\|)*(\w*)(?> |\t|\(|\)|!|&|\|)*(\w*)(?> |\t|\(|\)|!|&|\|)*(\w*)(?> |\t|\(|\)|!|&|\|)*(\w*)(?> |\t|\(|\)|!|&|\|)*(\w*)(?> |\t|\(|\)|!|&|\|)*(\w*)` does capture up to six symbols per match, however most of the groups are empty, since there's only one symbol on each line. Also, there could be more than six symbols on a given line, and I'd like to capture them all.

Is there a cleaner way to repeat the `(?> |\t|\(|\)|!|&|\|)*(\w*)` until the end of the line so that it captures all symbols?

I've tried nesting those parts of the expression in another group so a "multiple" quantifier could be applied, but that didn't seem to help. I'm probably missing something.

This is a regex question, but I added the C# tag, since I'm using regex on C# code and other languages may use different preprocessor syntax, such as seen here: [Extracting preprocessor symbols from source (C/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180427/extracting-preprocessor-symbols-from-source)

Comment: `^[\t ]*?#.*?$`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/0BV2yz/1

Comment: You just have to remove all the white spaces at the beginning of the line since c# ignores these white space.  So just change ^[\t ]* to \s* and get rid of the question mark which is equivalent to the asterisk.  The asterisk is zero or more while a plus sign is one or more. So use ^\s*#

Comment: What is to be returned if the line is `if (SYMBOL_1 && !SYMBOL_2) || !SYMBOL_3 || SYMBOL_4`?

Comment: I just updated the question to include what is returned for each match. The `if (SYMBOL_1 && !SYMBOL_2) || !SYMBOL_3 || SYMBOL_4` match should contain 4 groups `SYMBOL_1`, `SYMBOL_2`, `SYMBOL_3`, and `SYMBOL_4`.

If comment marks were added before `SYMBOL_4`, as in `if (SYMBOL_1 && !SYMBOL_2) || !SYMBOL_3 //|| SYMBOL_4`, only the first three symbols should be captured.

Comment: I just leave this quote :)
Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems. (c)